# When is a holomorphic map from a complex surface to a Riemann surface is a holomorphic family of Riemann surfaces?

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

A holomorphic family of Riemann surfaces of type $(g, n)$ is a triple $(M, \pi,B)$ defined as follows:

$\bullet$ M is a $2$-dimensional complex manifold (topologically, a $4$-manifold);

$\bullet$ $B$ is a Riemann surface;

$\bullet$ $\pi: M \to B$ is a holomorphic map;

$\bullet$ for all $t\in B$, the fiber $S_t =\pi^{-1}(t)$ is a Riemann surface of genus $g$ with $n$
punctures;

$\bullet$ the complex structure on $S_t$ depends holomorphically on the parameter $t$.

I wonder when is a holomorphic map $\pi:M\to B$ from a complex surface to a Riemann surface is a holomorphic family of Riemann surfaces of type $(g, n)$? In particular, why is a Kodaira fibration a holomorphic family of Riemann surfaces? (It's not clear to me that $S_t$ is holomorphic on the parameter $t$.)

A Kodaira fibration is a compact complex surface X endowed with a holomorphic submersion onto a Riemann surface $\pi: X\to\Sigma$ which has connected fibers and is not isotrivial.

Comment: What is your precise definition of "S_t depends holomorphically on the parameter $t$"? For me, it means that the fibration define a holomorphic curve in the moduli space, and this is more or less immediate by (semi)-universality of the latter (well, up to some technical point necessary to deal with curves with automorphisms).

Comment: In fact, recall that the total space of a Kodaira fibration is always  algebraic (because it is of general type).

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi  I think it means we have a holomorphic map from $B$ to the Teichmuller space of the fiber $F$. I can’t see why that is naturally holomorphic. And what’s the semi-universality?

Comment: Google "moduli space" and look for "fine moduli space". The moduli space of curves is not fine, but you can deal with this by suitable technical constructions (using rigidifications or passing to stacks). This essentially gives to you the map $B \to \mathcal{M}_g$, that turns out to be algebraic (since the family is  so). Then you can lift it to the Teichmuller space as an holomorphic map, using the fact that $\mathcal{T}_g$ is the orbifold universal cover of $\mathcal{M}_g$.

Comment: There are some technical issues, but morally things go in this way.

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi for the lifting to the Teichmuller space, do you use the lifting criterion from the algebraic topology? But lifting criterion says we have this lift iff the image of the $\pi_1(B)$ in $\pi_1(M_g)$ is a subgroup of $\pi_1(T_g)$, however $\pi_1(T_g)$ is trivial while $\pi_1(B)$ is not, how do you see the image of $\pi_1(B)$ in $\pi_1(M_g)$ is trivial then?